# dynamic_cast to derived class returns nullptr

Tags: c++

In the following code, why doesn't `dynamic_cast` produce a `Base *`?

```
#include <cassert>

class BaseI;

class SystemI {
public:
    virtual ~SystemI() {}
    virtual void remove(BaseI *) = 0;
};

class BaseI {
public:
    SystemI * system = nullptr;
    virtual ~BaseI() {
        system->remove(this);
    }
};

class Base : public BaseI { };

class System : public SystemI {
public:
    System() {
        Base base;
        base.system = this;
    }
    void remove(BaseI * basei) override {
        Base * base = dynamic_cast<Base *>(basei);
        assert(base != nullptr); // <-------------------- fails
    }
};

int main() {
    System sys;
}
```

My intent is to create a mechanism where components derived from `BaseI` automatically remove themselves from the system upon deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, a derived class object's "derivedness" is destroyed before the base class destructor starts to run. Thus, when the `Base` object goes out of scope, its (empty) destructor `Base::~Base` runs first; once this has completed, there is no `Base` object anymore, but there is still a `BaseI` object, which must subsequently be destroyed. When `BaseI::~BaseI` runs, therefore, and calls `remove`, the dynamic cast to `Base*` must fail.